# React axios patch request giving 401 error but authorization is provided

Tags: reactjs, django, react-native, axios, django-serializer

I am trying to add a user to a group with a axios patch request. the data is all correct but i get a 401 error even though i include the Authorization in the header. Code is below any help is greatly appreciated.

```
    handleJoin = (e, group) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        axios.get('http://localhost:8000/core/current_user/', {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: `JWT ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`
                }
        })
        .then((user) => {
            let group_data = new FormData();
            group_data.append('user', user.data.id);
            group_data.append('group', group.id);
            for (var value of group_data.values()) {
               console.log(value);
            }
            axios.patch(`http://localhost:8000/core/usergroup/${user.data.id}/`, {
                group_data,
                headers: {
                    Authorization: `JWT ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`,
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
            })
            .then((res) => {
                console.log(res.data);
            })
            .catch((err) => { 
                console.log(err);
            });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
```

Edit: Attempting to rewrite the request and changing the position of the group_data variable stops the 401 error but does not change the data in the model.

```
    handleJoin = (e, group) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        axios.get('http://localhost:8000/core/current_user/', {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: `JWT ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`
                }
        })
        .then((user) => {
            let group_data = new FormData();
            group_data.append('user', user.data.id);
            group_data.append('group', group.id);
            for (var value of group_data.values()) {
               console.log(value);
            }
            axios.patch(`http://localhost:8000/core/usergroup/${user.data.id}/`, group_data,{
                headers: {
                    Authorization: `JWT ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`,
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
            })
            .then((res) => {
                console.log(res.data);
            })
            .catch((err) => { 
                console.log(err);
            });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
```

Edit:

I changed the handler and now it is updating the group field but completely overwriting it. When i try to send group as a list it gives error expecting a int that represents pk. So my question is, is there a method to patch the model without overwriting the previous information.

Handler with group value as id

```
        e.preventDefault();
        axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/core/current_user/', {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: `JWT ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`
                }
        })
        .then((user) => {
                let group_data = new FormData();
                group_data.append('user', user.data.id);
                group_data.append('group', group.id);
                for (var value of group_data.values()) {
                   console.log(value);
                }
                axios.patch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/core/usergroup/${user.data.id}/`, group_data,{
                    headers: {
                        Authorization: `JWT ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`,
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    },
                })
                .then((res) => {
                    console.log(res.data);
                })
                .catch((err) => { 
                    console.log(err);
                });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
```

Handler with group as list

```
handleJoin = (e, group) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/core/current_user/', {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: `JWT ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`
                }
        })
        .then((user) => {
            axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/core/usergroup/${user.data.id}/`, {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: `JWT ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`,
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                }
            })
            .then((usergroup) => { 
                let group_data = new FormData();
                let prev = usergroup.data.group
                prev.push(group.id);
                console.log(prev);
                group_data.append('user', user.data.id);
                group_data.append('group', prev);
                for (var value of group_data.values()) {
                   console.log(value);
                }
                axios.patch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/core/usergroup/${user.data.id}/`, group_data,{
                    headers: {
                        Authorization: `JWT ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`,
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    },
                })
                .then((res) => {
                    console.log(res.data);
                })
                .catch((err) => { 
                    console.log(err);
                });
            })
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
```

The backend is written with Django and i realize the problem may be there instead of the front end. I am also posting my serializer and views in case they may be the problem. Any help would be really appreciated.

Serializer

```
    class UserGroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    groups = GroupSerializer(many=True, read_only=True,)

    class Meta:
        model = UserGroup
        fields = '__all__'
```

View

```
        class UserGroupDetail(APIView):
        def patch(self, request, pk):
            usergroup = UserGroup.objects.get(pk=pk)
            serializer = UserGroupSerializer(instance=usergroup, data=request.data, partial=True)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
                return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: Did you get a solution for this? getting same error with patch and push requests, however post is working

Answer (score 1):

Your authorization header should be

```
Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! i have tried this but it still give me the 401 error.